# Windows Dev Center - Page Not Found after attempting to sign up for an individual account ($19)

Tags: windows, center, account

After seeing some amazing stuff at Build 2016, I decided to sign up for a Windows Dev Center individual account ($19).  Once I went through the payment process, I was greeted with a Page Not Found.  Is anyone else getting this?  Does the Microsfot team responsible for Windows Dev Center monitor stack overflow?  Someone at MSFT suggested I post here.

I am getting the same error as in [this tweet](https://twitter.com/artistandsocial/status/715110050973487109).

Comment: Stackoverflow is a place to ask/answer programming questions. This is not a programming-related question.

Answer (score 1):

I tried again in Edge and this time it worked.  It looked like there may have been an update to the application, and not my switch to Edge that solved this for me.